# Typescript: How to map string type to generic with many different subtypes

Tags: typescript, generics

I am trying to create a typed interface on top of local storage where I can set/get from local storage in a typed way using only a string key. I want to have a mapping of the string types to generics that allows me to have custom serialization/deserialization.

The issue I am running into is that Typescript doesn't seem to be able to properly infer the types when I use a mapping object to go from the string type to the object generic. If anyone has some good advice on the best way to go about this, that would be amazing! ❤️

I have an example below that might explain my situation better:

```
type LocalStorageKey = "bool_test" | "num_test";

type LocalStorageKeyInfo<T> = {
  key: LocalStorageKey;
  getDefault(): T;
  serialize(val: T): string;
  deserialize(lsVal: string | null, defaultVal: T): T;
};

const BooleanSerializer = (val: boolean) => String(val);
const BooleanDeserializer = (lsVal: string | null, defaultVal: boolean) => {
  if (lsVal === null) {
    return defaultVal;
  } else {
    return lsVal === "true";
  }
};

const NumberSerializer = (val: number) => String(val);
const NumberDeserializer = (lsVal: string | null, defaultVal: number) => {
  if (lsVal === null) {
    return defaultVal;
  } else {
    return Number(lsVal);
  }
};

export const BoolTestKeyInfo: LocalStorageKeyInfo<boolean> = {
  key: "bool_test",
  getDefault: () => false,
  serialize: BooleanSerializer,
  deserialize: BooleanDeserializer,
};

export const NumTestKeyInfo: LocalStorageKeyInfo<number> = {
  key: "num_test",
  getDefault: () => 0,
  serialize: NumberSerializer,
  deserialize: NumberDeserializer,
};

const keyInfoMapping = {
  bool_test: BoolTestKeyInfo,
  num_test: NumTestKeyInfo,
};

export function getKeyVal(key: LocalStorageKey) {
  const keyInfo = keyInfoMapping[key];
  try {
    return keyInfo.deserialize(
      window.localStorage.getItem(keyInfo.key),
      // This line is the issue because deserialize's second arg is infered as never
      keyInfo.getDefault()
    );
  } catch (e) {
    return keyInfo.getDefault();
  }
}

// I want x to be a boolean here
const x = getKeyVal("bool_test");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get `x` to be `boolean` by adding a generic type parameter to the function to capture the actual type of the `key` that was passed in. You will however still need some type assertions in the implementation, as ts can't follow correlations between variables that well.

```
export function getKeyVal<K extends LocalStorageKey>(key: K) :ReturnType<typeof keyInfoMapping[K]['getDefault']>
export function getKeyVal(key: LocalStorageKey) {
  const keyInfo = keyInfoMapping[key];
  try {
    return keyInfo.deserialize(
      window.localStorage.getItem(keyInfo.key),
      // This line is the issue because deserialize's second arg is infered as never
      keyInfo.getDefault() as never
    );
  } catch (e) {
    return keyInfo.getDefault();
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMg9gYwIYBsDKw4CckHMIDSEIUAvFAEQBGccKA+sBAM7AVQA+lAdgK4C2jFmwDcAWABQk0JFiJUGbHkLEAktwBmcADwAVAHxkoAb0lQoAa2IAuOcnSYc+IiHETz+YABEIGpLxRgAAoASltdN3NmCCwAS1RYgC8IIIA3VHCwqFY47lxIqAATFhj4lCSUlGYANQzs4FzcTig+FBQAGiLff0DalEzwtwBfN0kEOG5WKAAhWhQIJG40UoTkrCM0upo6Be4QskMMRs2UELdxyeAZud2faLjVmI2qvtsc2Lzm1o6uvwDgV5QbbzRb7UiGUzuKCxDRQIIvVBkUjkb77SHmcxYCDAXhYbi-HoA1AFIZQCBVaDojFYnF4qAIlBI8gUBq8CAUEmSEaSMYTKYAOQEVBiywe5TWG3S-RaQpiYMODQ+uBOZ15lyggv4wqwdxW4qe5HhNTq70+XG+nWKf16dT4WrlBxMZmhsKNfSZMraaOdmOxuPxVsJfRJZIpTqhvtp+M12rdqFVUKGXNGEggAA8wNgrhcprM6LphC51FpbPB7IonCoQMWdMDdoZyFSrCBbNQ5kJWBR2s7PD5rcBbKFHX4Kd2ofcyhVbHmQUs9RUsGPzMUJ49pzdFrqxQux9ypKmM1moDmrpqC6wi5o4KX5A4lM41FftHbtQ3w+Zm627R22EuoL3un+Qd5SgAAGP9V31WwYxFec1j-Fc4IgaDZR1Ept3g5MeQkE9LEfLQAFkkDAMAlSMKlgR-dd80LfC4D-b8mFYFD+HPYBLy0XcU3TTMsCuDReG4BBgFiCZ-2xFw+m0AgyTTJhuEKZg7AURxlBcfQgk-KACH2awACU-TxXRwAgbQZAgOBYWbGsiJIpUAG0CAAXXsgByAD+1cpz9EkHijwEoSRLEzxJNQTSbGUu9Kxcb0oVw6yryMBLCOI0i8ns5snIKBoSCpSN-Tw6srwAOkQjCUh9DEAHcPkKOAquKlBbwrZRis8VQmH4cKiq0YrmxCP8MSgAB6YaoF0AALWIlPKbhoGmqBgAm+bmGYNkgQgZBeGiLpIIqVylOiC5CigJAsCaBaPg0GIIBOpAlLm1IYkqj86La7E+0JId7paCAnqwSqE3MUlkGABAJrhCBYqGmkCuSuB3u8QDAlCTkJCTfdRqgVQoCqxYrjTRa4A206gQ3fFlqxNUpkJ8gQuIPogjbOgfwoM4gA)